# Can I make a label display different text depending on a variable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I'm writing an implementation of *paper-scissors-rock* in Visual C#.NET. I want to have a a scoreboard in one corner, so I want to know if the content of a label can be changed by variables in the code. Can it?

Comment: Yes, Just set LabelX.Text.

Comment: *"content of a label"* - is label `Text` property. This can be easily discovered by a simple look into label properties (using winforms designer property window). Inability to do so definitely deserves downvote. Or is your problem something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the variable. If the variable is a `string` it's no problem and you can do it like this: `Label1.Text = yourString;`

However when the variable is of another type like `int` it's a abit harder to do. Luckily you are working with a label that accepts string and most types are easy to convert to string like in the `int` example: `Label1.Text = yourInt.ToString();`

In the end you just have to look up the type of the variable and see how you can convert it to the wanted type.

Answer (score 2):

of course, just use `Label1.Text = "yourString";`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think what you mean can be solved by using

```
if (variable == something)
{
    label.text = "something";
}
else if (variable == somethingelse)
{
   label.text = "somethingelse";
}
```

Comment: What for is `if ... else`? Maybe you need `switch` for all the cases and will assign each to `label.text`? :)

Comment: Well, both possible, but I think that the op is just starting his c# career, and then an else if statement is way easier

Comment: That was a kind of joke because I see no reason why `label.text = someVariable;` is not good enough